# Split into chunks of six entries each using bash

Tags: bash, shell

```
91
58
54
108
52
18
8
81
103
110
129
137
84
15
14
18
11
17
12
6
1
28
6
14
8
8
0
0
28
24
25
23
21
13
9
4
18
17
18
30
13
3
```

I want to split into chunks of six entries each.After that it will break the loop.Then it will continue the entries 7..12, then of 13..18 etc.

(for loop?continue?break?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `paste`:

```
paste -d' ' - - - - - - < inputfile
```

For your input, it'd return:

```
91 58 54 108 52 18
8 81 103 110 129 137
84 15 14 18 11 17
12 6 1 28 6 14
8 8 0 0 28 24
25 23 21 13 9 4
18 17 18 30 13 3
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$ xargs -n 6 < file_name
91 58 54 108 52 18
8 81 103 110 129 137
84 15 14 18 11 17
12 6 1 28 6 14
8 8 0 0 28 24
25 23 21 13 9 4
18 17 18 30 13 3
```